# Use of stl::map and stl::unordered_map for sorting the array data which contains a lot of repeated elements

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl, time-complexity, unordered-map

Please look at the solution 2 of this question from geeksforgeeks
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-sort-a-big-array-with-many-repetitions/
It uses the stl::map and says that the solution is O(n+mlogm), which assumes the that stl::map insertion and find are in O(1) time. Is this correct?

the code in the given link is :

```
void sort(int arr[], int n) 
{ 
   //1. Create an empty hash table. 
    map<int, int> count; 

    //2. Input array values are stores as key and their 
    //counts are stored as value in hash table. 
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++) 
        count[arr[i]]++; 

    map<int, int>::iterator it; 
    int index = 0; 

    //3. Consider all keys of hash table and sort them. 
    //In std::map, keys are already sorted. 

    //4. Traverse all sorted keys and print every key its value times. 
    for (it=count.begin(); it!=count.end(); ++it) 
    { 
        while(it->second--) 
        arr[index++]=it->first; 
    } 
}
```

Comment: It's customary to put the code into the question itself. It saves us clicks, and your question won't become useless in the future if the link rots.

Comment: Updated the question with the code i was talking about

Answer (score 0):

It’s just a typo for `std::unordered_map`, whose operations *are* *O*(1) on average.

Comment: But then , if we use unordered_map , then the elements inside this map will not be sorted and hence will not be in O(1) time which was assumed earlier in the code. I was wondering , is it really possible to do this in O(1) with any data structure.

Comment: @RahulAssassin: It says to (comparison) sort the (unique) keys as one of the steps.